# Getting junk/control characters in Kafka topic from confluent MongoDb source connector

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am trying to get data in kafka topic from confluent MongoDB source connector. Below is config of connector:

```
**{
  "value.converter.schema.registry.url": <-SR url->,
  "key.converter.schema.registry.url": <-SR url->,
  "name": <-connector-name->,
  "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector",
  "tasks.max": "2",
  "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
  "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
  "connection.uri": <-mongo-source-url->,
  "database": <-source-db->,
  "collection": <-source-tablename->,
  "publish.full.document.only": "true",
  "output.format.key": "json",
  "output.format.value": "json",
  "output.json.formatter": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.json.formatter.SimplifiedJson",
  "copy.existing": "false"
}**
```

I am getting data in kafka topic but key & value are like below:

```
**"key":"\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0005Đ\u0002{\"_id\": {\"_data\": \"ABCD123\"}}",
"value":"\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0005��\t{\"_id\": \"ABCD123\", \"name\": abc, \"id\": 174}"**
```

Can anyone has gone through similar issue?
My topic schema is in avro format that's why I need to use AvroConverter only. Also I have to use 'output.format' for key and value as 'json' only as source schema is not constant.

Would really appreciate any help here.

Comment: That's Avro data. If you want readable json output, use json converter

Comment: okay. So does it mean that we cant use AvroConverter with with json formatter?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this Mongo connector. It should be able to be used with Avro (you may want to try Debezium instead, though). I'm just saying that the output is a string representation of the Avro byte payload... What tool are you using to view the data?